# Is there a way to change the graphical user from the command line on Centos?

Tags: centos, gnome, teamviewer

I am currently using a remote log-in application (TeamViewer) on my Centos server. The application runs in the user's graphical session. I deliberately 'switched' users to see how my Teamviewer session would respond. I could no longer log in via Teamviewer. Is there a way to switch the graphical user back to my account from the command line? I want to be able to ssh into a box and resuscitate my Teamviewer session.

Answer (score 0):

If the `switchto` command is installed, it can be used to switch between virtual terminals. I am guessing the one you want is number 7, in which case the command to use is `switchto 7`.

I was dissatisfied with some aspect of how the original `switchto` was implemented and wrote [my own implementation](http://kasperd.net/~kasperd/linux_kernel/switchto.c), which works the same way except from some corner case where the original didn't do what I wanted it to.

But I would recommend you to reconsider how you manage your systems, since server management through `ssh` tend to work better than any GUI based tools.

Comment: Understood. I am using Teamviewer to get to a box which will in turn have VNC access to another box. The Teamviewer is a potential weak link should the existing user context change.